# How to enable MySQL INTO OUTFILE output to be writable by group / everyone?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, permissions, xampp

I just got a new laptop (an M1 Macbook running Mac OS Big Sur) and I'm having a time getting one of my projects set up locally; two large components of this project are a MySQL database and a PHP webapp, and on my machine I've got both running through non-VM XAMPP (version 8.0.8) - though technically, XAMPP only has MariaDB, not MySQL (but I've never noticed an issue).

One part of the webapp generates a dynamic .csv using MySQL's `INTO OUTFILE...` functionality. However, once MySQL outputs the file, the PHP script needs to read it and manipulate it before downloading it to the browser, so the user running the PHP script needs write access.

The script is located at `/Applications/XAMPP/project/webapp/download.php`, and everything was set to all-access with `sudo chmod -R 777 project/` (I know, bad practice, but this is just for development).

`exec('whoami')` tells me that the script is running under the `daemon` user from XAMPP's Apache server. The script is owned by `myusername` with a group of `admin` containing `root` and `myusername`.

When generated, the files from MySQL are owned by user `_mysql` with group `admin`, with permissions `-rw-r--r--`, i.e. 644. So, when this script runs, it generates the file but I get the following PHP warning upon a call to `file_put_contents()` after reading / working with file data:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/webapp/XXXXXXXXXX.csv): 
Failed to open stream: 
Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/webapp/download.php on line 26
```

I'm at a loss on how to get anyone but the mysql user writing to this file. The kicker is that my old machine - a 2013 Macbook Pro running Mojave - doesn't have any noticeably different configuration, and it works (it does use XAMPP 7.4.6 instead, but other than using PHP 7 instead of 8 the differences seem marginal). I've noticed there, the MySQL-generated files have `-rw-rw-rw-` permissions, so the admin group (or I guess everyone, as I don't believe daemon belongs to the admin group on there) can write to it - I just can't get my new computer to do it.

Aside from general fiddling of permissions (I'm no wizard with this kind of stuff), messing with groups, etc., all I've really tried is setting the `UMASK` MySQL environment variable in mysql.server and mysqld_safe; didn't seem to have any effect, and config changes like that make me leery given that my old computer needed none of it. And for the record, though not sure it's relevant - the `secure_file_priv` variable in MySQL is set to blank and root / localhost combination have file privileges; generating the file itself is not a problem.

How can I get things going without changing a line of code? It's clear the issue lies somewhere in my configuration. Not sure if it's worth mentioning, but I do have another installation of MySQL from homebrew...could there be some conflict there? That being said, my old computer also had another MySQL instance as well, but installed off the MySQL website.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to configure the permissions used for files created by `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`.

Comment: The permissions changed in MySQL 8.x, to be more restrictive.